# How to fetch code coverage for delta code and publish it as comment in git PR

Tags: jenkins, github, sonarqube, jenkins-plugins, jacoco

How to fetch only the code coverage for a new line of code from sonarQube and post it as a comment to git PR?

For instance: a project had 1000 lines in a branch and it's unit test coverage results are already in SonarQube. A new commit was pushed today with an extra 100 lines of code and additional test cases. These additional test cases cover 70 of the 100 new lines. Is there a way, to fetch the "code coverage on the new line of code" from the differential view of SonarQube and post it as a comment in gitHub? (in this case 70%)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a built-in feature since [SonarQube 7.4](https://www.sonarqube.org/sonarqube-7-4/) if you are using the official (commercial) pull request analysis.

We compute both the coverage of changed lines (same as your example) as well as an estimation of the coverage of the target branch after the merge.